# PIL Download for Windows Binary

Tags: python, download, python-imaging-library

I was wondering where i could download PIL (Python Imaging Library) as a windows 32bit binary? The official sites where it is available are not working, giving 500 server errors.
I run Python 2.7.

Comment: -1 as this is out of scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: Looks like the official download [site ](http://effbot.org/downloads/#pil) it back up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the main site is down, use [`http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) mirror, filename is `PIL-1.1.7.win32-py2.7.‌exe`.

Comment: Now that's a useful link, if I ever saw one!